# Orbits of left-multiplication from $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to learn moduli space of elliptic curves from different resources. But only a spacial class of elliptic curves where the lattice in the plane has "integer vectors" as generators. To study these I am trying to solve the following.
Given set $M$ of all $2\times 2$ integer matrices. Consider action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ over $M$ by multiplying on the left of matrix. What is set of orbits of this action.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your suggestions. I am trying to learn moduli space of elliptic curves. But only a spacial class where the lattice in the plane has "integer vectors" as generators.

Comment: You should include this information in your question (using the [edit](/help/editing) link below the question) and also include where this particular question arose (homework, book exercise, $\ldots$).

Comment: $SL_2$ acts on the left, not $PSL_2$.